# Azure create local site with resource manager

Tags: azure

Azure has two methods for creating resources.

- classic
- resource manager

The differences [are documented here:](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-classic-rm/)

It is easy to create a site to site vpn with the classic method as documented here: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

**Classic**

[image]

**Resource Manager**

In order to create a site to site vpn using resource manager, you need to setup a "local site". It is documented with the "classic" and with "powershell" but not "preview" ([documented here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/))

[image]

Does the azure portal support creating a local site? I'm able to create it from the command line, however nothing shows up in the web interface.

```
New-AzureLocalNetworkGateway -name LocalSite -ResourceGroupName foobar -Location 'West US' -GatewayIpAddress '8.8.8.8' -AddressPrefix '5.5.5.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

**VNets? sure you can**. This is available on the classic and resource manager.

[Create a virtual network using the Azure preview portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/)

[Create a virtual network (classic) by using the Azure preview portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-classic-pportal/)

**VPN gateways? doesn't look like it yet**. it appears that creating one with ARM is only supported using PowerShell for the time being (you've already provide the link that above, I'll [re-post it here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell/) just for easy referencing).

I even went to creating a test VNet on my subscription using ARM, and I couldn't get the controls for creating a VPN gateway.

During the general availability annoucement for the VPN Gateways using ARM, they never said that the controls will be available using the portal, all their documentations shows how to do it using the PowerShell commands, so I'm going to safely assume that nope, not supported yet. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-azurerm-versus-azuresm/

Answer (score 1):

things have changed a little bit. you can now create LocalNetworkGateways from the portal.

I've created a videos that goes through the process.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnFWG-ktT6Q